# Deploy public racket website

Tags: racket, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy a website that others can access in Racket to my school's server, but I am not sure what to do. For HTML files just having index.html in a public_html does the job. I can get the program below to work on my local machine (it deploys at localhost:8000/test.rkt), but I can't find any tutorial mentioning how to not use localhost.

```
#lang racket
(require web-server/servlet)
(provide/contract (start (request? . -> . response?)))

(define (start request)
  (response/xexpr
   `(html
     (head (title "TEST"))
     (body (p "1 2 3")))))

(require web-server/servlet-env)
(serve/servlet start
               #:launch-browser? #f
               #:quit? #f
               #:listen-ip #f
               #:port 8000
               #:servlet-path
               "/test.rkt")
```

Comment: Your school's server needs to be able to run Racket (or the executable you can create from your source code) in order to be able to run your page. Can you compile and then run the executable on your school's server?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're asking. You write "a website that others can access in Racket to my school's server". Where will the server be running? On your machine, or on the school's server? The way that you're calling serve/servlet should make your server visible both locally (using localhost, as you've done), and globally (to any machine that hits port 8000 on your machine), but there may very well be a firewall involved. Honestly, I think this question is really a general question about web servers, and not about Racket? Can you clarify?